# How can I submit a form in WordPress using AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms

I am struggling with submitting a form in WordPress using AJAX. In particular, can't figure out how to target a file where I can proceed the request.

Comment: refer this https://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-for-data-insertion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your form's action should point to admin-ajax.php and you should have a hidden field with your action's name:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="so44562011">
</form>
```

In your plugin or theme you should create an action that will handle request:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'so44562011' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'so44562011' );

function so44562011() {
    // your logic here
}
```